# GoalioRememberMeDoctrineORM how to make it work? (Remember Me feature for ZfcUser)

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

ive just recently started with zend2, now im trying to use [GoalioRememberMe](https://github.com/goalio/GoalioRememberMe) with [doctrine](https://github.com/goalio/GoalioRememberMeDoctrineORM) but i cant seem to make it work.

- The checkbox for the remember me functionality appears correctly.
- goaliorememberme.global.php is in config->autoload

ive put all manner of possible values in 'remember_me_entity_class' such as the custom user entity i use with zfcuser, GoalioRememberMeDoctrineORM\Entity\RememberMe and my own remember_me entity.
They all fail at login.
Is there some other steps im missing?

Comment: Can you elobarate more on "they all fail at login". What exactly happens when they fail. Do you get a error message or is it failing silently?

Comment: it fails silently, as if the user didnt exist. it doesnt give an error per se, it just fails to login in users already registered.

Comment: On the logs there is a service not found exception for GoalioRememberMe\Authentication\Adapter\Cookie